# In Chrome console, how can I print entered data?

Tags: javascript

I'm studying Javascript.
Todays's mission is print entered data on Chrome console.

I made some code that can type and submit button.
But I don't know how to print entered data on console.

I think 'console.log','getElementById' would be answer.
But I can't make code with those clues..

Anyone can help me please?
Thanks in advance.

```
<body>
<input type="text" name="mname" placeholder="Enter movie name" size="40">
<input id="active" type="submit" value="Search">
    <script>
        var m = document.getElementById('mname');
        console.log(m);
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: simply: `console.log(m.value)`

Comment: There is no id with "mname". Do you want to fetch element by its name ?

Comment: Please take time on upvote or accept the answer if it helped you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57704425/in-chrome-console-how-can-i-print-entered-data/57704499#57704499

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<body>
<input type="text" id="mname" placeholder="Enter movie name" size="40">
<input id="active" type="submit" onClick="consoleData()" value="Search">

</body>
<script>
function consoleData () {
  var m = document.getElementById('mname');
  console.log(m.value);
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the basic HTML tutorials for this, please follow below which is one of them.

```js
function print() {
  var m = document.getElementById('mname').value;
  console.log(m);
}
```

```html
<body>
<input type="text" id="mname" placeholder="Enter movie name" size="40">
<input onclick="print()" type="submit" value="Search">
</body>
```

> I believe this source may be useful to improve your knowledge 
>  https://www.w3schools.com/js/

Answer (score 1):

You should add an event trigger for the `console.log()`.
Like this:

```
<body>
    <input type="text" name="mname" id="mname" placeholder="Enter movie name" size="40">
    <input id="active" type="submit" value="Search" onclick="log()">
    <script>
        function log(){
            var m = document.getElementById('mname');
            console.log(m.value);
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I think 'console.log','getElementById' would be answer.

Yes, you can use these two methods to achieve your task. Here is a snippet with some points to consider:

1. Change `name` attribute to `id` attribute on input as `getElementById` requires it
2. Use `.value` to get the input's text
3. Add `onclick` attribute to link input to the `log` function

```js
function log() {
  var m = document.getElementById('mname').value;
  console.log(m);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="mname" placeholder="Enter movie name" size="40" value="Superman" />
<input id="active" onclick="log()" type="submit" value="Search" />
```